# JQuery .width() for this element

Tags: jquery

How can I get width of element which I css. My code:

```
$('a').css({'left':-$(this).width()/2})
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: $(this) in my code will select document. I want it return current a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback as the property value which can return the actual style value

```
$('a').css({
    'left': function () {
        return -$(this).width() / 2
    }
})
```

Comment: how can I apply this code for dynamic data loaded by ajax